# ProgressBar erro incomum

Tags: android, mobile

Não estou entendendo o erro, quero fazer um coisa simples com Progressbar mas não dá 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference.

Sei que esse erro é porque não foi iniciado o Progressbar, mas realmente eu iniciei ele dessa forma. Mesmo assim dá erro.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Só pra ter certeza, esse progressbar tá sendo chamado onde? Activity, Fragment, Dialog...? E se puder passar mais parte do código em que ele está, também ajuda

Comment: Não tem mistério no código não, está em uma Activity, só queria ver como funciona o progressBar, mas está dando esse erro na hora da visualização esse progressbar é o progressbar infinito o cíclico. Na verdade vou usar em uma Ansytask mas também dá o mesmo erro. Fiz o teste com progressbar na minha Activity e dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Eu queria mesmo é usar o progressbar da seguinte forma dentro da Ansytask no onPreExecute() mostrar o progressbar e no onPostExecute deixar ele invisível. Lembrando que é apenas o cíclico.

Comment: Confere esse id `R.id.progressBar3` com o layout, pois o erro está dando a entender que a variável `progressBar ` não referencia objeto algum.

Comment: Bom dia, @StênioBarrosodeMoraes! Por simples que seu problema pareça, apenas com essas duas linhas de código não será possível resolve-lo, pois as respostas não passarão de especulações. Edite sua pergunte e inclua o código faltante

Comment: Eu estou trabalhando com Mapview na activity a questão do erro é que só posso iniciar o progressbar depois que iniciar o Mapview porque isso acontece não sei, por isso coloco o codigo progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); na ultima linha e funciona.

Comment: Agora quando tento usar dentro de uma Ansytask dá erro mesmo passando os parâmetros para o construtor da Ansytask.

Answer (score 0):

Gente já me falaram uma vez não tá dando certo começa do zero. Simplesmente criei outra activity e copiei e colei o código e pronto funcionou. A minha activity por algum motivo estava bugada. Não sei o que era simplesmente ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar3; estava retornando null. Quando nada está funcionando devidamente volte a estaca zero.